# Possible to download all the packages from "groupinstall" and then run ( yum --nogpgcheck localinstall *.rpm )?

Tags: linux, repository

This is the original command:

```
yum groupinstall "Desktop" "Desktop Platform" "X Window System" "Fonts"
```

I would like to create 4 folders for these. (1 folder for each).

```
mkdir Desktop
mkdir Desktop_Platform
mkdir X_Window_System
mkdir Fonts
```

Then I would like to run:

```
yum groupinfo Desktop
```

to see what packages are in that group, and download each one to the first folder above, via:

```
yumdownloader --resolve <package_name>
```

Same thing for every other folder and group above. So I repeat this process 4 times, until each folder has all the RPM files for each group.

Now I re-install CentOS Linux minimal, and then I want to install all of the groups without running:

```
yum groupinstall "Desktop" "Desktop Platform" "X Window System" "Fonts"
```

Can it be done by going into each one of those folders individually and running this command:

```
yum --nogpgcheck localinstall *.rpm
```

?

Answer (score 4):

Yes as you've described it, it sounds doable. I think I would be inclined to do the following steps.

#### Setup directories

```
$ mkdir {Desktop,Desktop_Platform,X_Window_System,Fonts}
```

#### Download RPMs

Then run these types of commands to download the RPMs for the given groups:

```
$ repoquery --qf=%{name} -g --list --grouppkgs=all "Fonts" | \
     xargs -I{} repotrack -a x86_64 -p Fonts/ {}
```

You can wrap it in a for loop too:

```
$ for i in "Desktop" "Desktop_Platform" "X_Window_System" "Fonts";do  
    repoquery --qf=%{name} -g --list --grouppkgs=all "$i" | \
       xargs -I{} repotrack -a x86_64 -p $i/ {}; 
  done
```

This will go through each group and download the packages into their respective directories.

#### Re-installation

Then use the command as you've described:

```
$ yum --nogpgcheck localinstall {Desktop,Desktop_Platform,X_Window_System,Fonts}/*.rpm
```