# How to download group packages "Server with GUI"?

Tags: rhel, yum, repository

I was trying to follow [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/89757/98471) to download all packages for "Server with GUI". Am I doing something wrong?

OS: RHEL 7.5

```
[root@test rpms]# repoquery --qf=%{name} -g --list --grouppkgs=all "Server with GUI" | xargs -I{} repotrack -a x86_64 -p "Server with GUI"/ {}
[root@test rpms]# echo $?
0
[root@test rpms]# ll
total 0
[root@test rpms]#
```

Thanks !

Comment: Does `repoquery --qf=%{name} -g --list --grouppkgs=all "Server with GUI" ` return anything?  Try running `repoquery -g -a` to get a list of all the groups your system sees.

Comment: First query is not returning anything. `repoquery -g -a` is giving a list but "Server with GUI" is not listed. I have already installed "Server with GUI" in that system, is that causing this?

Comment: Perhaps you didn’t install a Server configuration? Or you don’t have the right RHEL channels enabled?

Comment: `yum` is working perfectly if that's what you are asking and if I try `yum groupinstall "Server with GUI"`, it is also listing all packages to be installed.